# Android - Communicating between Fragments

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to access a function in one Fragment (f1) from another Fragment (f2).  It seems that i have to make my function in f1 public and static to be able to access it from f2.

I've read that it's not a good idea to access one Fragment from another, so i've tried to make f2 access my Activity, which then connects to the function in f1.  Although, even doing it this way, i still have to make my function in f1 public and static.

I don't reuse the Fragments, i simply have them in a ViewPager for swiping back and forth through the Fragments.

At the moment i have a lot of static variables because i have to make my functions static to access them from other Fragments.

Am i going about this the wrong way?  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look into using the EventBus library

Comment: Why do you need to send data between fragments? Can you be more specific about the information you are passing around?

Comment: For example:  One Fragment may contain a ListView of restaurants and when you click on an item in that ListView it calls a function in another Fragment, with contains Google Maps, that shows where that restaurant is, as well as passing other information about that restaurant which was held in the ListView item.  The ViewPager then sets the Maps Fragment to the current item so the user can see where that restaurant is in on the map.  I hope that explination helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're going down a road of much pain unless you are very controlled about what you do.

First of all, sharing state through static methods and variables is a fairly awful way of doing things, and static members won't be able to access anything in the instance of the fragment.  If you really think you need to use static methods, don't bother putting them in the fragment classes.  They don't provide an advantage there.  Put them in a common class that they all reference.

Second of all, if you're using a ViewPager with fragments, you can't be guaranteed that any given fragment's view hierarchy even exists at any moment in time.  This is because ViewPager typically only keeps fragment views alive that are on the current page or on +/- 1 offset from the visible page.  So if you need to tell a fragment at offset +2 from the current fragment, you won't be able to make visible changes to it.

Instead, the easiest thing to do is create an object that maintains whatever state you want to share between the fragments, and have them all make changes to that one object.  If you need instant changes to other fragments, you can use something like an event bus to have those changes communicated to other active fragments.

What you're trying to do is in general fairly complex.  Expect to spend a lot of time designing a correct solution, and be sure to learn how fragments and ViewPager works very well.

Comment: *like an event bus* - Do you happen to mean the literal [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)?

Comment: Hi Doug,  i have set my ViewPager's setOffscreenPageLimit to be the amount of the number of Fragments i have, so they all stay alive in memory.  I know this is not the best approach, because it consumes resources with Fragments staying alive that may not be used, but it works really well, it's fast and the Fragment's don't have to get remade, so i'm only going to my server once to get data in each Fragment, instead of having a round trip each time each Fragment is getting re-created and attached.

Comment: @cricket_007 There's no reason to be opinionated about which event but to use.  There's lots of them.  I'll let to OP decide what to use.

Comment: @Nickmccomb The round trips to the server isn't an issue.  Just do it once in the host activity and cache all the results.  Then let all the fragments feed off that data.

Comment: Ahhh good idea Doug!  I'm starting to realise i've structured my app in a way that's making me run into these problems and i'm trying to program around them when i should just bite the bullet and re-structure.  Thanks for all the help Doug!

Answer (score 2):

You got two questions

## 1. Am i going about this the wrong way?

Yes, its not recommended to have the methods & variables declared static just to make them used to access from outside of your class.

## 2. Is there a better way?

Yes, declare the methods as public (but not static) inside its fragments.
From the activity (which is hosting the fragments) get the reference to the fragments using FragmentManager classes methods findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag() then call the methods.

Sample :

```
Fragment fragment =    
                   fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag.findFragmentById
                                 (R.id.fragment);
or

Fragment currentFragment =  
                      fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragmentTag");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really require both of your functions to be isolated, you can use Broadcasts. Just send a Broadcast from one fragment and have the Broadcast receiver in the other fragment.